# TortoiseGit завершил выполнение некорректно (код завершения 1)

Tags: unity3d, github, tortoise-git

[image: Пытаюсь отправить на GitHub в приватный репозиторий проект Unity, но каждый раз вылазит одна и таже ошибка]

Пробовал уже использовать команды:

`git gc --force / git fetch -p`
Не помогло, что можно сделать??

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/470029)

Comment: Так а Вы проблему-то исправили, из-за которой ошибка появилась?

Comment: нет к сожалению...(